# VMware не устанавливается на Windows 7

Tags: vmware

Vmware workstation при установке выдаёт ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия любой кнопки - да/нет - пустое окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема?

Comment: пробовали нажимать "да"?

Comment: после нажатия любой кнопки остается просто пустое установочное окно.

Answer (score 1):

Решение этой проблемы ест на официальном сайте: 
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1027986

Как вариант, спасает:
Открыть реестр

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones

Удалить ключ с именем "[]"

Comment: нет  такого ключа http://i.imgur.com/PADsc59.png

Comment: и по ссылке той тоже ничего не решило проблему

Answer (score 0):

Проблема как раз в замазанном синем. Там или пробел, или русский символ, или что-то еще.

1. Создайте папку `C:\tmp`.
2. Откройте у себя System (`Win+Break`)/Advanced System Settings/Environment Variables.
3. Найдите там `TEMP` и `TMP`, скопируйте куда-нибудь их значения.
4. Исправьте `TEMP` и `TMP` на `C:\tmp`.
5. Перезапустите установку.
6. После установки откатите `TEMP`/`TMP` на старые значения.

Comment: Да, имя пользователя на кириллице. 

Тоже самое, только без имени пользователя теперь
http://i.imgur.com/00FLagF.png

Comment: попробуйте найти в распакованных файлах msi и запустить его напрямую. если не найдете сразу - вызовите распаковку, `installer.exe -e c:\tmp`, где installer.exe - имя того инсталлера, который вы запускаете.

Comment: ничего не помогло :(